# How disable ecto insert cache?

Tags: elixir, ecto

My app inserts millions records. Every second size `ets` data table increases on several mb.

In `deps/ecto/lib/ecto/query/planner.ex` I find `cache_insert` function that inserts data to ets. How to disable this behaviour?

My function for insert:

```
defp to_cache(links) do
    recs =
    Enum.uniq(links)
    |> Enum.filter(fn (link) -> (link != nil and link != "") end)
    |> Enum.map(fn link -> %{link: link}  end)
    |> Enum.each(fn link ->
         %Crawler.MongoLinks{}
            |> Crawler.MongoLinks.changeset(link)
            |> Crawler.MongoRepo.insert()
     end)
end
```

`link` is struct like `%Crawler.Links{link: "http://example.com/page.html"}`

Comment: Are you using string interpolation in your queries? The cache shouldn't fill up if you're doing something like `Repo.insert(%MySchema{foo: foo, bar: bar})` even if you call it with a million different values as only one query will be cached.

Comment: add function to description

Comment: Are you using MongoDB?

Comment: Mongo - for cache and PG as main db.

Comment: You find a solution or not ?

Comment: no, only new fetch